# Montar Grid de acordo com tags XML

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

Estou com uma dor de cabeça em meu projeto aqui...

Tenho que consumir dados de um *webservice* que os manda em formato *xml*. No atual momento, eu consigo receber esse *xml* do *webservice*, mas não consigo varrer todo o *xml* e montar meu grid de acordo com todas as tags que tem no *xml*.

O que acontece é que o *xml* tem a raiz e vários sub elementos que não são lidos.
O layout do xml é esse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<certidoes>
   <codigo_retorno>99999</codigo_retorno>
   <mensagem_retorno> </mensagem_retorno>
   <qtd_registros>0</qtd_registros>
<certidao>
   <codigo_hash />
   <metodo />
   <numero_solicitante />
   <numero_recebedor />
   <tipo_registro />
   <data_solicitacao />
   <nome_registrado_1 />
   <nome_registrado_2 />
   <novo_nome_registrado_1 />
   <novo_nome_registrado_2 />
   <data_ocorrido />
   <data_registro />
   <matricula />
   <obs_solicitacao />
   <emolumentos>0</emolumentos>
</certidao>
</certidoes>
```

O que acontece é que na hora de criar o Grid com essas tags, o Grid é criado somente com as trÊs primeiras tags, ou seja: `<codigo_retorno>`, `<mensagem_retorno>` e `<qtd_registro>`... E falta as outras informações...

Existe alguma forma pra que eu consiga fazer esse Grid com todas as tags do XML ?

E como eu poderia fazer para que se a tag `<qtd_registros>` tiver valor igual a 0, eu não mostrar, digo, ignorar, e não mostrar no Grid ? Ou seja, mostrar os dados que tem valor maior que 0.

O código que uso pra fazer essa leitura, eu peguei no tutorial [do macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/12/09/xml_cur2.htm), onde tem um botão que tem os seguintes códigos?

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(@"C:\caminho\do\arquivol");
        dgvXML.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

E no meu cenário uso da seguinte forma, pois é dinâmico o retorno do *xml*:

```
DataSet tabela = new DataSet();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(temp));
        tabela.ReadXml(ms);
```

Como posso fazer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode ler o XML como XDocument e converte-lo para um objeto da seguinte maneira:

Defina uma classe para representar os valores do XML:

```
public class Certidao
{
    public string CodigoRetorno { get; set; }
    public string MensagemRetorno { get; set; }
    public string QtdRegistros { get; set; }
    public string CodigoHash { get; set; }
    public string Metodo { get; set; }
    public string NumeroSolicitante { get; set; }
    public string NumeroRecebedor { get; set; }
    public string TipoRegistro { get; set; }
    public string DataSolicitacao { get; set; }
    public string NomeRegistrado1 { get; set; }
    public string NomeRegistrado2 { get; set; }
    public string NovoNomeRegistrado1 { get; set; }
    public string NovoNomeRegistrado2 { get; set; }
    public string DataOcorrido { get; set; }
    public string DataRegistro { get; set; }
    public string Matricula { get; set; }
    public string ObsSolicitacao { get; set; }
    public string Emolumentos { get; set; }
}
```

---

Faça a leitura usando a classe `XDocument`:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
....

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
List<Certidao> certidoes = new List<Certidao>();

foreach (var elmCertidao in doc.Root.Elements("certidao"))
{
    Certidao certidao = new Certidao()
    {
        CodigoRetorno = doc.Root.Element("codigo_retorno").Value,
        MensagemRetorno = doc.Root.Element("mensagem_retorno").Value,
        QtdRegistros = doc.Root.Element("qtd_registros").Value,
        CodigoHash = elmCertidao.Element("codigo_hash").Value,
        Metodo = elmCertidao.Element("metodo").Value,
        NumeroSolicitante = elmCertidao.Element("numero_solicitante").Value,
        NumeroRecebedor = elmCertidao.Element("numero_recebedor").Value,
        TipoRegistro = elmCertidao.Element("tipo_registro").Value,
        DataSolicitacao = elmCertidao.Element("data_solicitacao").Value,
        NomeRegistrado1 = elmCertidao.Element("nome_registrado_1").Value,
        NomeRegistrado2 = elmCertidao.Element("nome_registrado_2").Value,
        NovoNomeRegistrado1 = elmCertidao.Element("novo_nome_registrado_1").Value,
        NovoNomeRegistrado2 = elmCertidao.Element("novo_nome_registrado_2").Value,
        DataOcorrido = elmCertidao.Element("data_ocorrido").Value,
        DataRegistro = elmCertidao.Element("data_registro").Value,
        Matricula = elmCertidao.Element("matricula").Value,
        ObsSolicitacao = elmCertidao.Element("obs_solicitacao").Value,
        Emolumentos = elmCertidao.Element("emolumentos").Value
    };

    certidoes.Add(certidao);

}

gridView.DataSource = certidoes;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Nesse caso, todos os dados serão retornado como `String`. Recomendo fazer as conversões adequadas a cada tipo, por exemplo:

```
QtdRegistros = Convert.ToInt32(doc.Root.Element("qtd_registros").Value),
DataSolicitacao = Convert.ToDateTime(elmCertidao.Element("data_solicitacao").Value),
```

Porém será necessário tratar caso a caso para evitar erros com valores nulos ou vazios.

[Fiz um NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4P5VvJ) com um exemplo da leitura.

Comment: Cara, ta dando erro nessa linha: XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(temp)))...

Comment: Qual erro? Se a variável temp é uma string com seu XML, pode usar `XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);`. Eu copiei esse `new Memory Stream` do seu código, supondo que a variável `temp` é uma string com o XML.

Comment: Mas é isso mesmo, é uma string com o xml. O erro que dá que ele espera um XmlReader no parametro do XDocumento... E por exemplo, se eu precisar varrer várias certidoes no xml e mostrar uma a uma, em linhas, como posso fazer ? E outra coisa, se eu fizer dessa vou conseguir mostrar todas as tags ? Porque pelo que entendi, só mostra as tags da certidão...

Comment: O `XDocument.Parse(xml)` funcionou? Você terá várias tags `<certidao>` no mesmo XML ou terá vários XML's com essa mesma estrutura? Preste atenção no código que ele está lendo todas as tags. Nas três primeiras linhas da leitura, estou lendo direto da raíz, por exemplo: `doc.Root.Element("codigo_retorno")`. Depois eu leio da tag `<certidao>` a partir de uma variável que contém sua referência: `XElement elmCertidao = doc.Root.Element("certidao")...elmCertidao.Element("codigo_hash").Value`

Comment: Ah soja. Vão ter várias tags `<certidao>` em um xml só. Funcionou, mas quando chega ali no `object` da erro de referencia nula.

Comment: Alterei a resposta. Criei uma classe para representar os valores do XML e fiz a leitura considerando vários elementos `<certidao>`. Dá uma olhada aqui https://dotnetfiddle.net/4P5VvJ também para ver funcionando.

Comment: O elmCertidao não pode ser usado... Ta acusando que ele não pode ser usado aqui.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24627/discussion-between-marcusvinicius-and-erik-thiago).