# Ler arquivo HTML

Tags: c#, html

Em meu projeto eu preciso ler um arquivo HTML que no código fonte tem uma estrutra de um xml. Preciso ler esse arquivo HTML, pegar o valor das tags do xml que tem lá fazer todo um processo para salvar esse dados no meu banco de dados....

Ler um xml, meu sistema lê numa boa, mas preciso que meu sistema seja capaz de ler um arquivo HTML também.

Como posso fazer isso ? Não tenho ideia de onde começar.

## Estrutura do meu arquivo HTML

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body><certidao>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
<subtag></subtag>
</certidao>
</body></html>
```

*Preciso ler tudo que está dentro da tag raiz `certidao` e desconsiderar as tags HTML*

*A página html está salva no computador e não é preciso acessar o link e sim o caminho do arquivo.*

Comment: Ler HTML ou XML é análogo. Você tem um código de leitura de XML?

Comment: Pra ficar mais fácil cigano, existe uma forma de que eu consiga remover as tags do html deixando a tag certidão ? O que acontece é que no codigo fonte da página HTML, ou seja, o conteudo da página HTML, é um xml, ou seja, tudo que está dentro da tag certidão....

Comment: O sistema não pode abrir o arquivo, editar ele retirando a parte indesejada e depois salvar o arquivo como um XML?

Comment: É porque a logica que tenho aqu @AndrewPaes lê um xml, só que a lógica mudou, agora preciso ler um arquivo html que tem como conteudo o xml.

Comment: Não seria possível usar o `XDocument` ou `XmlDocument` para ler o arquivo? A partir daí, é simplesmente necessário extrair o conteudo do `<certidao>`.

Comment: Ao menos que `XmlDocument` precisa do `<?xml?>` lá em cima.

Comment: Eu já uso o XDocument @brazilianldsjaguar. Sò que na hora de iterar sobre os elementos, ele passa direto e não lê as tags.

Comment: Entendi. Consegue postar esse código? (e desculpe aí o português, não é o meu idioma natal!)

Comment: To fazendo igual ta aqui [nessa minha pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68219/montar-grid-de-acordo-com-tags-xml) só dando os replaces pra tirar as tags html e deixando somente as do xml, ou seja, as que estão dentro de certidão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

```
PM> Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
```

Segue um pequeno código de exemplo

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("arquivo.html")
foreach (HtmlNode certidao in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//certidao"))
    foreach (HtmlNode subtag in certidao.SelectNodes("//subtag"))
        Console.WriteLine(subtag.InnerText);
```

Tem um exemplo com o seus dados modificados no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g0zJ53)