# Retirar strings de arquivos html

Tags: c#, string

Em meu projeto preciso ler o o conteudo de um arquivo HTML como dito [nessa minha pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74720/ler-arquivo-html). O que acontece é que consigo varrer o arquivo, mas tem um comentário que eu queria tirar.

A peculiaridade é que esse comentário é sempre mutável, então como que eu posso fazer com que o c# retire todo o trecho de código que aparece ?

O comentário que aparece é esse aqui:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0103)https://sistema.registrocivil.org.br/buscas/certidoes2aViaGerarXmlBusca.cfm?pedido_certidao_id= -->
```

Existe alguma maneira de eu tirar esses elementos de comentário do HTML(`<!---->`) e tudo que está dentro desse elemento ? Pois como ele é sempre mutável, não dá pra usar o Replace e tirar.

Será que alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode remover os comentários utilizando *Regex*, da seguinte maneira:

```
string semComentarios = Regex.Replace(stringHtml, @"<!--(.*?)-->", String.Empty);
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando [nesse fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LSUFiK).

Comment: Isso mesmo, essa é a melhor solução para o prolema.

Comment: Assim não captura comentários multi-line. Tens que usar `RegexOptions.Singleline` para tratar o input `stringHtml` como se fosse uma única linha.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius só um adendo, teria como usar uma regex para retirar as tags do HTML, tipo `<html>`,`</body>`, deixando o conteudo do XML lá intacto ?

Comment: Apesar do comentário estar direcionado ao Marcus, eu digo que dá sim. Só seguir o modelo do Marcus. Regex é simples, não tem complicação. Você vai substituir o que está na expressão, por outra que no caso da do Marcus é uma string.Empty, ou seja, vazia. Aí é só usar a imaginação que você vai longe. Good code.

Comment: @pnet eu já tentei, só que o que acontece é que tira todas as tags, inclusive as do xml, e eu preciso mante-las, se não minha lógica de ler a página não funciona. =(. Você poderia ajudar ? Se souber de alguma coisa, seria de grande ajuda! Não queria abrir uma outra pergunta, pois acho que é o mesmo tema que tem aqui. =(

Comment: É melhor abrir outra pergunta, senão os caras vão bloquear a pergunta, já que essa é mais direta, ou seja, tags HTML e BODY. Vai por mim, abra outra específica. Aqui, é melhor abrir várias perguntas do que tentar emendar uma, aí os downvotes vão correr soltos até o bloqueio da pergunta. Até porque você já encerrou e muita gente não visualiza perguntas com respostas já encerradas.

Comment: Bem, eu criei uma [nova pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74840/abstra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-com-v%C3%A1rios-replaces). Se caso puder me ajudar, iria ser bem vinda qualquer solução!

Answer (score 2):

Faça o seguinte :

```
    int indexIni = 0;
    int indexFim = 0;
    string html = @"<div> dfklçbndflçbndfblçdfnmblçdfmblçdfmblçdmfblçdfbmç<!-- saved from url=(0103)https://sistema.registrocivil.org.br/buscas/certidoes2aViaGerarXmlBusca.cfm?pedido_certidao_id=21716443 --></div>";

    Console.Write(html);

    indexIni = html.IndexOf("<!--");

    indexFim = html.IndexOf("-->");

    if (indexIni != -1 && indexFim != -1)
    {
        html = html.Remove(indexIni, Math.Abs(indexIni - (indexFim + 3)));
    }

    Console.Write(html);
```

Comment: Qualquer duvida na aplicação da solução estou a disposição.

Comment: Caso ele use tags do asp.net, os comentários seriam @**@ e o exemplo do Luã não iria contemplar isso. Acho que por regex seria mais viável, não que o Luã esteja errado, de maneira nenhuma, é só que eu teria que definir mais variável e por regex, basta eu acrescentar na expressão o que eu quero remover. Só uma dica.

Comment: Sem problemas @pnet, infelizmente meus conhecimento de "regex" são bem limitados por isso não mostro uma solução desse tipo. Mas realmente seria uma solução melhor.

Comment: Não Luã, não foi isso, apenas quis dizer que se o cara tiver outra string de comentário, terá sempre que criar uma nova variável, mas a sua solução está ok, só quis que ele levasse em consideração isso.

Comment: Não tranquilo, não levei a mal seu comentário realmente seria uma solução melhor. Criticas construtivas são sempre bem vindas. É nois.

Comment: @LuãGovindaMendesSouza a sua solução é ótima! Dá pra usar numa boa aqui no meu cenário!