# Abstração de código com vários Replaces

Tags: c#, html, xml, regex

Tenho esse bloco de código:

```
 xml = xml.Replace("<html>", "");                                    
 xml = xml.Replace("<head>", "");
 xml = xml.Replace("</head>", "");
 xml = xml.Replace("<body>", "<certidoes>");
 xml = xml.Replace("</body>", "");
 xml = xml.Replace("</html>", "</certidoes>");
```

A minha dúvida é: Existe alguma forma de abstrair essse bloco de uma forma que fique mais amigável e simples ?

Preciso que retire as tags do html e coloque a tag certidões.

*Nota: xml = é um xml que tenho no conteúdo da página HTML*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, eu tentaria algo que não é tão mais simples, mas é bem mais limpo e mais efetivo, pois o  seu arquivo poderá ter outras tags ou "lixo" dentro das tags.

Tenho visto suas outras questões sobre esse seu arquivo HTML que tem um XML dentro.

```
string arquivoHTML = @"<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
                        <head>
                        <meta charset='UTF-8' />
                        </head><body>
                        </body>
                        </html>";

arquivoHTML = arquivoHTML.Replace("<body>", "|").Replace("</body>", "#");
arquivoHTML = arquivoHTML.Substring(arquivoHTML.IndexOf('|')).Replace("|", "<certidoes>");
arquivoHTML = String.Concat(arquivoHTML.Substring(0, arquivoHTML.IndexOf('#')), "</certidoes>");

Console.WriteLine(arquivoHTML);
```

Comment: Cara, nessa sua solução funcionou bem, mas a tag <certidoes> não se encontra no arquivoHTML, então no replace eu a coloco. Dentro dessa sua solução, existe alguma forma de coloca-la? E teria como colocar uma breve explicação do que ta acontecendo ?

Comment: Como assim; colocá-la? Você deseja inserir a tag <certidoes> dentro de um HTML e depois retirar o HTML. Você consegue me explicar todo o processo que você está fazendo? Pois assim podemos tentar chegar em uma solução mais simples.

Comment: Bem, o que eu faço é pegar uma string mesmo que seja multilines ( o @ permite escrever multilines ), assim simulo que você abriu um arquivo e passou ele todo para uma string. Depois pego essa string e substituo as tags <body> para poder encontrar mais fácil. Depois retiro tudo que está antes do "|" e depois do "#". Resultando somente a tag <certidoes> e o que houver dentro dela.

Comment: Andrew vou explicar, espero ser claro.. kkk. O que acontece é que para que eu consiga ler meu xml, eu preciso ter uma tag raiz. Essa tag raiz é a certidões. Mas quando baixo o arquivo HTML a tag `<certidoes>` não esta no documento, então o que eu faço ? Dou um replace dessa forma:  `xml = xml.Replace("<body>", "<certidoes>")`. Então ou seja, eu retiro a tag do HTML `<body>` e coloco a tag `<certidoes>` no lugar. E da mesma forma acontece nessa linha: `xml = xml.Replace("</html>", "</certidoes>")`. Acho que consegui explicar!

Comment: Cara que simples! Isso ajuda muito! Mas espero que eu tenha sido claro no outro comentario!

Comment: E dentro da tag <body> você tem um XML, certo? Logo, então porque você precisa criar essa tag <certidoes> ao invés de simplesmente tirar o html e deixar as tags XML que já estão atualmente, e com esse XML alimentar no C# uma coleção que será as certidões?

Comment: Mas se você quiser eu edito a resposta para incluir a tag <certidoes>

Comment: Por que na lógica de varrer o xml, na hora da leitura, quando o leitor chega na tag <certidao> ele a ignora e não consegue ler o xml. Então eu preciso de uma tag raiz pra que ele a ignore, ou seja, a tag <certidoes>  e leia tudo que ta na tag <certidao>.

Comment: Eu gostaria cara, se puder, iria ser muito bom!

Comment: FUNCIONOU CARA! VALEU DEMAIIS !